# ArXiv data download per category

Tags: data-request

I want to download all articles related to a set/category, say cs.AI. I came across bulk S3 access, but that contains all the articles and is about 725GB of today (02-April-2017).

References:
https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism to do this by category. Crawling arXiv will result in a block (https://arxiv.org/help/robots). Instead, you'd want to use the S3, in combination with the OAI-PMH and then sort out based on the relevant category locally (https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data).

Comment: If you use the OAI-PMH API you can select different sets (categories) for download: https://arxiv.org/help/oa/index The sets are listed here: http://export.arxiv.org/oai2?verb=ListSets